# QQ plot for multilevel logistic regression

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I'm running the multilevel logistic regression, and I hope to create a diagnostic plot for the model.But I found the previous qqnorm() function isn't available for multilevel logistic regression. So I find syntax in "DHARMa" package and produced QQ plot as below. I have questions that if the interpretation for this plot is the same as the plot produced by qqnorm() function.

```
simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = rl3)
plotQQunif(simulationOutput)
```

[image]